# Get the min value from different tables and save on a result table

Tags: mysql

```
Table_1

+------+-------------+
| id   | value       |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | 1.58        |
| 2    | 8.88        |
+------+-------------+

Table_2

+------+-------------+
| id   | value       |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | 2.15        |
| 2    | 7.50        |
+------+-------------+

Table_3

+------+-------------+
| id   | value       |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | 9.58        |
| 2    | 2.88        |
+------+-------------+

Result

+------+-------------------+
| id   | value             |
+------+-------------------+
| 1    | 1.58 (min value)  |
| 2    | 2.88 (min value)  |
+------+-------------------+
```

Howdy, I am not very familiar with mysql.

I want to calculate the minimum value, with respect to the ID, from different tables and store it on a Result table. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `union all` in a subquery.  Then use the `min` aggregate on the results:

```
select id, min(value) val
from (
    select id, value
    from table_1
    union all 
    select id, value
    from table_2
    union all
    select id, value
    from table_3
) t
group by id
```

---

Or alternatively you could `join` the tables together and use `least` (assuming all tables have the same number of `id` fields and only have 1 row per `id`).

```
select t1.id, least(t1.value, t2.value, t3.value) val
from t1 
  join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
  join t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

---

Edit: In regards to your comment, just add `CREATE TABLE`.

```
create table newtable
select ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm confused, I don't see the Result table in your code.

Comment: What if my table already exists. So `INSERT INTO Result (id, value) VALUES select ...` ?

Comment: @NoSssweat -- get rid of the `values` keyword... To create a new table, use `create table result select...` and to insert into an existing table use `insert into result (id, val) select id, val...`